# OAuth 2.0 client IDs

Tags: oauth, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I would like to know if Google Cloud Platform have any policy or process where in Google or your system deletes automatically the OAuth Client ID's if not in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the client id from google.

Now google and your application dont have any connection until unless you make it synchronize.

Google doesn't delete anything without intimating you. If it did, surely it will bring it to your knowledge.

Note: check once again, you might have looking somewhere else your client ID.

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful information. Appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not delete clients on your account without you asking them to.   I have several clients which were created 8+ years ago which i use maybe once or twice a year that are still there.

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful information. Appreciate your assistance.